# Public /Private encryption logic for multiple clients

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I have a scenario in which I have to implement a security according to following:

- Server encrypts a password with Key_Private and sends this encrypted password to all clients
- Clients have only Key_Public which they can use to decrypt this but cant encrypt any new password with this key.
- I can generate multiple Key_Public for multiple clients.
- I need to control the length of Public key (should to less then 20 char)

I have tried AES encryption but I am not able to find any simple code.

Comment: Do not tag your question with the `c#-4.0` tag unless you are explicitly having a problem with a C# 4.0 compiler feature.

Comment: One Password for all clients? Wouldn't it be better to ask each client for their public key, encrypt their individual password with that key, send it to them and let them decrypt it, with their private key?

Comment: Corak, suggestion is correct. Generate a secure session AES key, encrypt it with the client's public key, and send it to the client.

That session key should expire, and should be used to encrypt further communication.

Comment: Also, AES is a symmetric encryption algorithm; not a public/private key algorithm. Look for RSA samples instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm doesn't work, as it's backwards.

You can't decrypt using a public-key. Public key's are used to encrypt only. A private key is needed to decrypt. This is the basis for Public/Private key encryption.

Instead you want to use session key negotiation.

1. Client connects, it sends its public key to your server.
2. Server generates a secure random AES session key, along with appropriate expiry, and appropriate anti-replay values
3. Server encrypts secure random AES session key-blob with client public key
4. Server sends encrypted blob to Client
5. Client decrypts session blob using Client private-key
6. Client sends acknowledgement message, encrypted with session key
7. Server and Client begin secure communication with shared session key.

Some caveats:

1. The server should probably make sure the client is trustworthy before starting a session. This can be done using an out of band step (ie the public key is registered by a trusted third party). Or as is common with modern API's, the server generates the public/private key-pair, sends it to the client, and keeps ahold of the public-key.
2. The server should properly expire session keys, to prevent replay
3. The client (if you control them) should probably verify that the server is trustworthy (ie using the servers well-known public key)